# Change chat font from Verdana to Arial

Tags: feature-request, chat, fun, fonts

Verdana doesn't allow [Z̨͚͎͚̲͚̳̫̀̎͐̋̐͌͊͐͟͡ḁ̜͍̠̫̪̥̐ͣ͑ͣ͑ͫ̿̑͞l̶̶͕͈͍̉̆̋̍̅͋͐ͣ̍͝g̤̻̮͎̗͐̋̑̾ͬ̽͋͟o̜̹̜̙͕͉ͬ́͊ͤ͗̊̇ ̶̠̹̗̄̅̽͛͡T̳̤̓ͥ̀ͪ̍̕͞e͛͌̊ͪ̃͏͏̜͙̥̭̙͕̜͇x̨̱̖̘̹̩̬̮ͯ̎ͨ̓͒͘͠t̳͕̘̫̰͖̩ͯͫ̆ͨ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4451158#4451158) to be used, whereas Arial does.

I propose changing the default chat font from Verdana to Arial.

Comment: Note: Arial is used when Verdana does not exist.

Comment: Also, why is Zalgo text a good thing?

Comment: Probably because you probably might not like it....?

Comment: -1 sorry, as much as I love Zalgo text it's place isn't here

Comment: @Robotnik I made this suggestion in jest.

Comment: And this just appeared: [What is this mark over the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139210/what-is-this-mark-over-the-question) ;P

Comment: @YannisRizos lol, I didn't mean to cause so much trouble :P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ṡ̲̣̿̾̌̽̈́ͧ̄t̜͚̠͇͉̲̑̑̒̈͑ͪă̝̫̭͎̝̬̜̽ͅt̻͍͔̖͕̤͓͗̒ͫͣ̐̍͆̇ǘ̦͉͊̐̀́ͧ̑ͅs̘̫̬̹͓̯͔ͦ̅̏ͪ ̖͑̇͊ͅd̫͍̹͐ͣ͂̎ͧͬ̚e͇̯̲̎ͦ͛̒ͦc̱̙̦̮͚͍̯͛ͫͯͪ͌ͭl̞̗͇̮̩̠͙̋̓̓ͪͮ̾i͍̘̬̰͚̬̼͎̐̄̊̅ͫͅn͉͔͍͇̂͂̎e͎̯ͣ͆̾ͯ̎͒̀d̫̼͕̜̩̈̑ͨ,̪̝̥̰͍̭̿ͣ͒̊͑̂ͥ͐ ͍͔ͦͥͮt͙͔̭͍̞̺͛̽ͬͦ̈́̊ͧͦĥ͚̱̫̲̟͚̫̉̑ͮ́̍ͅi̻̦̖͈̜̰̗ͮ͆̾̈ͨͫ͛̎ͬs̝͍͙̻̮̪̣̦̓ͥ̈͛ ͙̭̯͎͙̾̂̈̈́̓̿ͤͮͧw̜̤̙̭̦̤̼̠̿̈́̌ͨͮ̎ͣ͋̎i͖̳͓͖̗̠͂̈́̿̊ͭ͋l̦̫̙ͩ̉ͫͩͪͫͅĺ̤̹̣͕͙̠̘͕̜ͩ͐ͫ ͈̙̳̟̭̰ͭ͂ͪͥͅg͔̝͈̟̖̯͕͙͌̈̂e̱̯̐̿̍͊ͭ͛̈t͚͍̙̙̬̝̩͎ͯ̐̾̂ͅ ͎̣̰ͩͦ̃̐͛̈o̥̝̊̐̿̎ͫ͒l̞̻̹̄d͙̗̞̖͍̹͖̈́͐ͧ̏̎ͮ̀̚ ͉͔͈̎r̖͍͈͍ͥ͐ͮe̖̝̞̫̤͙̤ͩ̿̈́̐ͪͣ̀ͅa͈̜͙̟̦̗̋́̂l̯̫̥̖͎͍͖̣͛͑ͨͤ̓l͖͙̪͉̙̰͛̎͋ͅy̫͍͕̅̾̎ ̗͇̞̬͕̥̗ͨ͂̇̎̒ͅf̮̱̬̤͊̊̋̀͗̽̏͒̾ͅa̟̼͚͖̲͇̭̥̅͗̽ͦ̿͐̐̚s͔͖̦̰͕͚͊̇̃t͓̯͖̗͍̠͒̌̀ͬ.̳̭̼͇͐̓͐ͦ͑̓͗̓ͬ

Comment: It's incredibly annoying on the front page. *[Contemplates running breaching experiment on SO]*

Comment: @RobertHarvey - It seems that would be a good experiment to run. I noticed that there are definitely layout issues when a lot of those undefined character boxes start showing up. It didn't seem to affect the parser though.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Zalgo text all the things on April 1, 2013!  just a suggestion...

Answer (score 15):

That's a feature. Also [Arial](http://modernl.com/article/5-terrible-fonts-that-you-should-not-use-in-print-design) has a bit of a bad reputation among designers.

[image]

Comment: `That's a feature` Preparing ourselves for a career at Microsoft, are we?