# What is this mark over the question

Tags: support

When I open a site I see a mark over a question.See screen shot.[image: error]

When I open the question mark is not remove.It still appear.

[image: error1]

is this bug or?

Comment: [He comes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/414076)

Comment: Zalgo text is referenced in the question in the screenshot, next time do a simple web search before asking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I͓͖̦̞̫ͬ͆̎̑t͙̖̮͔̻̰̜͉͗́'͇̜̱̦͔̫ͥͯ͛s̖̭̹̻̖̐̍͆ͧ̑̚ ͕̟̩̺̮̦̗̿ͤͥͬ̔Z̝͖̠̯̝̃͊ͪͬͥ͌a̰̻̝̠̝̥͐̒͗l͖̥̪̩͖͍̫ͬ̒̓ͤ͆ͅg̪̘̝̱͚͊͂̐ͮ̅ͫ̑o̭̱̱̍̅ ̲̗̖̱̳͋̌͆͋ͭ͌̏t̗͇̘͙̩̺̥̣̄̈̏͆͆̔ͪ͑e̙͕̝̜̞͇͉̗͔͊̈́̾̀x̰̣̖̠̠̲̳ͨ͌̋̈́͛ͥ̀̚̚t͕͈͓̤͖͒ͧͦ̓ͦͦ̍̀̔,̜͔̘ͫͫ͒̈́̒ͮ ͈̲̰̇ͦ̿͌n͓͇̼̣̩͇ͯ͂̉̀͐̿o͖̬͎͂̏͑ͬ͗ͪ̎ͧt͕͙͕̬͑ͫ͐h̥̺͇̤̪͖̎ͭ̉i̱̗͖̲̩̔̔͐̃n͇͈͕͖̿͆ͨͫ͐̂͐g̟͎̯͓̫͉̏ͥ̍ ͓͎͚ͤͭẗ̘̟̘̲ͯ́̈o̫̮̹̮͚̓̓̃̓̉ͧͭ ̼̦̺ͣ̊̏ͦͅͅw͕̔̋͛̆ͪͤȯ̙̗͎̬̭̩̘̱͛̓̏r̦̅r̭̤̤͔̬̘̄ͤ͌̐ͫ̿̉̇ý̦̹̯̼̘̠̬̈ͬ̌͂̿ ͇̪͙̲͍͈͍͔͈̐̉̉ͦ̑͆ͧ̚ȃ͔̯͚͎̋̐ͣ̍̅̊b̻͓̦̜͋̎͛͒̉̾o̖̲ͤͦͦ̌͌u̮͔ͫͦ̐̑̇ͭͅț̙̯̊̔ ̭̤͙̼̜́͆;̪̰ͥ̋̎̔)͖̲͓̟͖̹̫̥ͭ̍

Read: [How does Zalgo text work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work) & [Unicode subscripts and superscripts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts)